# jQuery show next image on click doesn't work with .first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to fade into view the next image `toggleImg()` is called from an onClick, however when we get to the end of the list and I start from the beginning again the fade effect doesn't work.

I assume it has something to do with the way the HTML is loaded in the dom and that the last image tag has a higher priority (as its further down the dom).

Do you know why the fade effect doesn't work when we reach the bottom of the list and start from the beginning again?

```js
$('.next').click( function() {
  toggleImg();
});

function toggleImg() {
  //Setup vars
  var current = $('ul#feature-image li.current');
  var next = current.next();

  //tag this guy to be deleted later
  current.addClass('old');

  //check if were at the end of the list
  if (next.length != 1) {
    current = $('ul#feature-image li').first();
    current.addClass('current imgFadeIn');
  } else {
    current.next().addClass('current imgFadeIn');
  }

  //delete the last guy now the animation is complete
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('ul#feature-image li.old').removeClass('current old imgFadeIn');
  }, 700);
}
```

```css
.next{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.imgFadeIn {
  animation-name: imgFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes imgFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

ul#feature-image {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

ul#feature-image li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 700px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

ul#feature-image li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

ul#feature-image li.current {
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
}

ul#feature-image li.current img {
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="feature-image">
   <li class="current"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200" alt="img"></li>
   <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x230" alt="img"></li>
   <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x100" alt="img"></li>
   <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x250" alt="img"></li>
</ul>

<div class="next">next</div>
```

As requested JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Lm99d6f0/1/
* Notice the fade, until the last list item

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with images from for example placeholder.com (https) and add relevant HTML to give us a [mcve]

Comment: Where are you calling `toggleImg()` from? This appears to be an incomplete sample of your code

Comment: Added a click event to the snippet... Also added a JSFiddle

Comment: The problem is that you don't fade out your `.old` so your `.current` is fading -in *behind* the .old.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add z-index to .old element.

```
ul#feature-image li.old {
    z-index: 98;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lm99d6f0/2/